# Somekind of "Cookies Manager" for Firefox 5?

Tags: firefox, cookies, session

I'll explain what I need.

Somedays ago, Google changed the way Google Apps store the login cookies. Making identical as a normal Google (@gmail) account. Before this, I was able to be logged in with my @gmail.com account and my google apps account simultaneously.

Now, with this change, I can't be logged in both.

So, is there some kind of "cookies manager" extension (like Session Manager) so I can switch between personal and work accounts?

If not, is there any workaround to stay logged in both accounts?

Please avoid suggesting "use different browsers", I want to achieve this using just Firefox 5.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google allows you to be logged in with [multiple Google account simultaneously](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2010/08/google-multiple-sign-in-now-available.html) in the same browser. The only thing you have to do is enable it in your Google account setting. To do so:

- In Gmail (or any google app) click on you profile picture and click on `Account settings`
- Under Account overview you should have `Multiple sign-in`, click on `Edit`
- Turn on the multiple sign-in by checking the `On - Use multiple Google Accounts in the same web browser.`

Comment: Great, didn't know about that. Thanks